# Silverlight MEF WCF Reference

Tags: silverlight, wcf, mef

I am creating a Host SL app that will serve up several "Plugins" Each of these plugins can reference their own WCF service. When i import these into the Host app using MEF it says it cant find the endpoint.

What is the best way to handle these endpoints. I am trying not to have to handcode each endpoint everytime we need to release a new plugin

Comment: How else would the plugin know where to find a service unless you tell it where it is? Are you looking for some WCF discovery mechanisms?

Comment: The plugin would know about the service. I dont want the host SL app to know about the service when the host is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these two line below allowed me to use that service reference without the config file exporting

```
  Private binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
Private WithEvents _Misc As Service_Misc.Misc_CallsClient = New Misc_CallsClient(binding, New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61928/Misc_Calls.svc"))
```